# How to left join in Codeigniter with aggerate function like SUM on basis of a date range

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables,
 
expenses category -> id, name, budget 
expenses ->id, date, expenses_category, amount

I want to select some **expenses** data withing two date range and SUM(amount) so that i can compare it with the budget column of **expenses category** table. The problem is i want to select all the **expenses category** whether it is on **expenses** table or not. So i used left join in codeigniter but every time i get only the category data which are on both table just like inner join. So far I tried this.

```
$this->db->select('ec.expensescategory_name,ec.budget, SUM(e.expenses_amount) as amount')
     ->from('expensescategory ec')
     ->join('expenses e', 'ec.expensescategory_id = e.expenses_category','left');
$this->db->where('e.expenses_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end)).'"'); //this like seem to creating problem,  but i need this line.
$this->db->group_by('e.expenses_category');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: The conditions for the left joined table Should be in the JOIN, not the WHERE

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. The join condition is in join not in where.

Comment: 'e.expenses_date BETWEEN...'